# How do I get the TX Key from the GUI Wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, privatekey

I'm trying to verify a payment but I'm not sure how to get the TX Key from my history on Monero Wallet GUI.

Answer (score 6):

First note that you can only obtain the private tx key for outgoing transactions, because it's randomly generated by the *sender*. In the GUI, first go to `History` tab. Subsequently, you can obtain the private tx key by clicking on `Details` of the relevant outgoing transaction.

Lastly, bear in mind that if you have to rebuild your wallet cache (after you, for instance, deleted it) you'll lose your private tx keys.

Comment: Thanks, My tx Key doesn't actually show. I just have the tx ID and the paymentID. Is there a way to enable this on the GUI version of the wallet? Or is its default setting on?

Comment: It should be on by default. Are you using a wallet that was created by the CLI?

Comment: Yeah I am, I'll clear the cache and do a few more new transctions to see if it works again. Thanks.

Comment: That may not resolve your "issue". A quick workaround is as follows. First, copy the `monero-wallet-cli` that is bundled with the GUI to the same directory as your wallet file is in. Second, open `monero-wallet-cli` and open your wallet by typing your wallet name (and entering your password). Third, type the following command: `set store-tx-info 1`. Fourth, type `exit` to save and exit the wallet. Lastly, open your wallet with the GUI. It should now save the private tx key for every outgoing transaction you make. P.S. You don't necessarily need to have a daemon running for this workaround.